# protractor wait for multiple objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

i'm loading somthing like this in DOM using AJAX:

```
<div class="elm_class"></div>
<div class="elm_class"></div>
<div class="elm_class"></div>
```

and then I need to wait for n elements presents in my protractor test. My best try was:

```
function needTrue(css,i){
    e = element.all(by.css(css));
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    if(e.length>i){
        return EC.presenceOf($$(".heading-description.uplevel").get(m1I));
    }else{
        return setTimeout(needTrue(css,length),1000);
    }
}

browser.driver.wait(needTrue(".elm_class", 3) , 10000);
```

but it doesn't even work this way throwing error

> maximum call stack size exceeded.

I would appreciate if someone could explain me how can I bring back to the wait function "promise" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`browser.wait` automatically loops up to the specified number of milliseconds until it returns `true` so you don't want to put a setTimeout inside it. Also you will want to use `.count()` not `.length` for the number of elements found by `.all`

```
function needTrue(css,i){
  e = element.all(by.css(css));

  // count the number of elements found
  return e.count().then(function(elementCount) {
    // if not enough elements, return false so browser.wait will keep looping
    return elementCount >== i;
  });
};

browser.driver.wait(needTrue(".elm_class", 3) , 10000);

// after waiting for the elements, check whatever
// I don't use EC, so I don't know if this part of the code actually works
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
expect(EC.presenceOf($$(".heading-description.uplevel").get(m1I))).toBe(true);
```

Comment: This work well. Thanks for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Make a *custom Expected Condition* to wait until `n` matching a selector elements are present:

```
function presenceOfAll(elements, n) {
    return function () {
        return elements.count(function (count) {
            return count >= n;
        });
    };
}

browser.wait(presenceOfAll($$(".elm_class"), 3) , 10000);
```

What is important to note here is that the *`presenceOfAll` returns a function* that `browser.wait()` would execute until it resolves into `true` or a timeout reached.

Comment: nice, was looking for a way to do this.